# Need Help Identifying Strap Securing Dryer Vent Hose

Tags: vent, hardware

I have existing clips or straps (I'm not sure which is the correct term for these) that holds a dryer vent hose in my laundry room. It almost looks like a flat chain where the holes allow for screws to pass through to hold it in place. I'm interested in getting more, but have no idea what they're called. Does anyone know what these are called?

[image]

Comment: An odd variant of pipe strap, perchance, but pipe strap is nearly always just a normal rectangular strip with holes in it. Unsolicited opinion - change as much of that corrugated hose as you can out for smooth solid metal - it traps lint much less and is easier to clean.

Comment: Old plumbers tape 50 years ago that was normal , now straight edges. I agree getting rid of flex on a dryer is a good safety upgrade. I just searched for plumbers tape and that and PFTE wer the big hits do it is not just me calling it that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've typically just seen that called metal strapping or steel strapping.

Home depot sells a similar thing in their ventilation accessories section, and they call it 'perforated metal hanger straps': https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-Perforated-Metal-Hanger-Straps-3-4HS/100396917

[image: metal strapping]

Most metal strapping I've seen has straight sides, instead of wavy ones like yours has, but for this application there should be no difference.

Comment: I have always referred to it as plumbers tape. It used to be ribbed like the pic from the OP. I think it is probably cheaper to manufacture with straight sides. But you are correct it is the same.

Comment: The OP appears to be located in Canada.  I've purchased metal strapping identical to what he shows in his photo from Home Depot in Canada.  Probably a different supplier than HD in the states.

Comment: The pictured version would be more material efficient cutting multiple strips from a wide sheet, as the holes would be offset so the wide part of one strip was the narrow part of the two on either side, and you'd get more total strips than the simple straight-sided strip. Needs a fancier cutter, but you get more product per raw material input.

Comment: Searching for "metal hanger straps", as mentioned in the Nate's reply led me to something similar on Home Depot's Canadian site: https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/building-materials/plumbing/plumbing-accessories/pipe-hangers.html. Thanks!